# PERL - check if c:\temp has any files in it, if empty - delete c:\temp directory

Tags: perl

I need an IF statement that will check if c:\temp has any files in it.. If it is empty, I will want to delete that c:\temp folder. I want to delete the c:\temp directory ONLY if there is nothing in it.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rmdir.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete files use [unlink](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unlink.html). Unlink takes a list of filenames which you can get from [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html).

The easy way is to not use an if-statement:

```
unlink glob 'c:/temp/*';
```

To delete the entire directory, if empty:

```
$dir = 'c:/temp';
@files = glob "$dir/*";            # Get files in c:/temp/
rmdir $dir unless(scalar @files);  # Remove directory if empty
```

Comment: `glob "$dir/*"` will return an empty list if `$dir` contains files whose names start with '.'.  (Which means the `rmdir` will fail, which is what you want, but there's no point in using `glob` in the first place.)